# Shirt deforms when parenting to Rigify Armature

Tags: rigging, rigify

So I Have a model the I've got set up with rigify.
[image]

The armature is not in rest position at the moment. But setting the current T-pose as the rest pose does not fix the issue. I don't understand why that is not working.
[image]
[image]

As you can see the shirt keeps deforming.

Comment: Share your file. https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: It is up now. thanks

Comment: So here's what I've found, as far as I can tell rigify doesn't let you change the rest pose. I found it was better to just model the shirt on the rest pose. All I had to do was slowly move the arms down and have a cloth sim. Would still be interested in knowing if you can change the rest pose.